# Evaluating a single char in an if statement: C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

I am having some troubles with my if loop.

First off I have I assigned char sign.

```
 void evaluate_ps(istream& input) 
 {
    char sign;
    input >> sign;
    cout << sign << endl;
    check(sign);
 }
```

That prints / so my sign has the value '/'

Then I go to my void check(char operation) function

```
 void check(char operation)
 {
    if(operation != '-' || operation != '+' ||
      operation != '*' || operation != '/')
       {
       return false;
       }
       else return true;
 }
```

and it's returning false... WHY!!!! I can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Minor style issue (unrelated to the question): the result of the expression in the `if` clause *is* a boolean value.  You can just `return (operation != '-' && operation != ...)`.  Code that looks like `if(x) return true; else return false;` should raise a red flag.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if loop".  A loop is a statement that executes repeatedly: `for`, `while`, `do-while`.  An if statement is merely an if statement.

Comment: To complete Keith Thompson you means to say your if **block**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant all your `||` to be `&&`:

```
if(operation != '-' && operation != '+' && 
  operation != '*' && operation != '/')
```

Otherwise, it will always enter the if-statement since a character will always not equal one of 4 different things.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you are using the `||` (OR) operator. When `operation` is `/` the check `operation != '-'` returns true. Since `||` is short circuited, the entire expression returns true.

Change it to && (AND):

```
if (operation != '-' && operation != '+' &&
   operation != '*' && operation != '/')
```

Another way to write this is:

```
if (!(operation == '-' || operation == '+' ||
      operation == '*' || operation == '/'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is responding to the / not equaling one of the other values

Think about "or" even in a general sense

if blue is not green or is not red or is not blue say nope

you would need to do something like the following:

```
if (operation != '+' && operation != '-' && operation != '/' && operation != '*') {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

this way its like this

if blue is not green and is not red and is not blue say nope